# XNA List For loop

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, xna

I'm having trouble running my loop which draws different images on the screen. This is the list I created which is all in my game class:

```
RepMeter = new List<>();

RepMeter.Add(RepOne);
RepMeter.Add(RepTwo);
RepMeter.Add(RepThree);
RepMeter.Add(RepFour);
RepMeter.Add(RepFive);
RepMeter.Add(RepSix);
RepMeter.Add(RepSeven);
RepMeter.Add(RepEight);
RepMeter .Add(RepNine);
RepMeter.Add(RepTen);
RepMeter.Add(RepEleven);
RepMeter.Add(RepTwelve);
RepMeter.Add(RepThirteen);
RepMeter.Add(RepFourteen);
RepMeter.Add(RepFifteen);
RepMeter.Add(RepSixteen);
RepMeter.Add(RepSeventeen);
RepMeter.Add(RepEighteen);
RepMeter.Add(RepNineteen);
RepMeter.Add(RepTwenty);
```

My Update Code:

```
if (activeCharacter.DestY >= 600)
{
     for (int RepMeter = 0; Rep < 20; i++)
         RepMeter[i];
}
```

This is my draw code:

```
if (RepMeter.RepOne)
{
     spriteBatch.Draw(RepOne, new Vector2(690, 29), Color.White);
}
else if (RepMeter.Two)
{
     spriteBatch.Draw(RepTwo, new Vector2(690,29), Color.White);
}
else if (RepMeter.RepThree)
{
     spriteBatch.Draw(RepThree, new Vector2(690,29),Color.White);
}
```

Can someone please tell me why my RepMeter will not change to the next RepMeter picture within the list?

Comment: Please reformat your code..

Comment: The code doesn't make any sense what so ever... even when you ignore the formatting! See: `for (int RepMeter = 0; Rep < 20; i++){ RepMeter[i]; }` What?!

Comment: Your update code isn't updating anything. There should be something like `RepMeter[i] = xy;` or `RepMeter[i].Something = xy;`.

Comment: I reformatted your code. Take the changes to heart and follow a similar format in future, not only [so] posts, but also your private code - trust me, it will help a lot. Also, I fixed a few clear syntax errors in your code (because I'm assuming it compiles, also, please copy code into the question, don't rewrite it, and construct a [Minimal, **Complete**, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) - feel free to modify this if that's not actually the way your code looks like.

Comment: @Dukeling Thank you for your advice! The only problem is that RepMeter now says it does not exist in current context. Do you know why this is?

Comment: How do I declare RepMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess since your code is kinda strange and it wouldn't even compile.
Anyway probably what are you trying to do is something like this:

```
    //this variable store the current texture index that will be displayed
    private int currentRep = 0;
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (activeCharacter.DestY >= 600)
        {
            currentRep++;
            //this line makes sure the current number doesn't point to an index higher than the number of items stored inside your list
            currentRep %= RepMeter.Count;
        }
    }

    public void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(RepMeter[currentRep], new Vector2(690, 29), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
```

this should work(not tested), clearly you need to make sure that RepMeter is a List<Texture2D> and that what you are inserting in it are actually Texture2D...

Anyway if that's your actual code I suggest you to start with something simpler.

NOTES & EXPLANATIONS:

1. in general you what to update you login in the update method and draw inside the draw method.
2. you must Begin and End your spritebatch in order to draw.

Comment: I think this is along the right line. The only problem is that RepMeter now says it does not exist in current context. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @brade where do you declared RepMeter? that means that RepMeter is not visible by Draw method. This occur if RepMeter is not declared as a variable inside the class body.

Comment: Everything is all in one class. Really sorry but I'm not too sure what you mean as I have been programming for 3days. How do I declare RepMeter?

Comment: I need to use a different operator as '%' is skipping a few of the images. Any idea what I can do to prevent this? there are 20 textures and it skips a few of them.

Comment: @brade it can't be %= fault. % is modulo operand, it just return the remainder of a division. If you see skipping it can only mean you're adding to currentRep more than once. If the only place where you adding is Update, then consider to place a breakpoint inside the update method and one inside Draw. If the update breakpoint fire twice or more per draw you're doing something wrong.